# Class Library - Static Library - Linker Issue LNK4221

Tags: c++-cli, static-libraries, class-library, static-classes

I am using VS2008, Class Library template, with /clr. 
I wanted to have a managed Class Library.
Everything works fine when I have the library compiled as a dll.

Header file: multiclasses.h

```
#pragma once

namespace multiclasses
{
    public ref class Class1
    {
    public: int a, b;
    private: int c, d;
    public: int add(int a, int b);
    private: int hadd(int a, int b);
    };

    private ref class Class2
    {
    public: int a, b;
    private: int c, d;
    public: int add(int a, int b);
    private: int hadd(int a, int b);
    };
}
```

Source file: multiclasses.cpp

```
#include "multiclasses.h"

namespace multiclasses
{

    int Class1::add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    int Class1::hadd(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    int Class2::add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    int Class2::hadd(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

When I change the Configuration Type to Static Library(.lib) I get the linker warning:
warning

*warning LNK4221: no public symbols found; archive member will be inaccessible*

Consequently The project using this library gives:

*Error  1   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001) multiclasses.Class1::add*

*Error  2   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000002) multiclasses.Class1::hadd*

*Error  3   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000004) multiclasses.Class2::add*

*Error  4   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000005) multiclasses.Class2::hadd*

Is there any way I can have a class library compiled as a static library(.lib) ?
Can I export classes in a static library? Is that fundamentally wrong trying to export classes in a static library?

Comment: Not supported: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/303e0a3b-8ecf-45f2-90f0-873d2679acb8/

Comment: http://gumdroplab.blogspot.com/2007/08/linking-to-ccli-static-libraries.html